# Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, ldap

How to get the details of the deleted objects from Active directory using LDAP.

Comment: @JasonMiesionczek Provide an answer in english (`en-US` or `en-CA`). If another language is needed, the poster might be able to convert it to their own.

Comment: @Loganathan : The first answer seems to be correct. May be you can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The deleted objects are stored in the separate container, to retrieve the objects have the look on [this technet site](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd379509%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

It is the inbuilt feature and should have the operating system of Windows Server 2008 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

*This answer comes from [Rodney Anderson](http://mailto:itconsultant@mail.uch.org), contractor who sits next to me and happens to know AD quite well. He says email him with any questions you have (link provided)

Use dsquery.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/258310  (LDAP Query)

...the other method is a DSquery from the command line using the following command you should be able to retrieve most attributes which remain in the tombstone (everything in one line): Just keep in mind that this query will not necessarily return all attributes which are preserved in a tombstone - some critical objects and changes of the list are hardcoded and will remain in the tombstone no matter what the searchflags state. This is the solution I used and it will take some tweaking for their domain.
dsquery * cn=schema,cn=configuration,dc=yourcomain,dc=com 
  -filter "(&(objectClass=AttributeSchema)(searchFlags:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=8))"
  -scope subtree -attr name

Answer (score 0):

On MSDN there is a [nice article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188700.aspx#S4) on finding tombstone objects in Active Directory using the .NET framework [DirectorySearcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.aspx) class.

Answer (score 0):

Well unfortunately there isn't all that much data available from a deleted object.  Only about enough data is retained to be able to replicate the deletion to other DC's from my experience. You can get what is available through System.DriectoryServices.  Some of this seems to have to do with security and not wanting people to root around looking at old items.

Answer (score 0):

To get the details of Deleted objects from active directory using LDAP server is before getting the details we should be aware of the administration limits.These administration limits are as such like InitRecvTimeout,MaxActiveQueries ,MaxConnections,MaxConnIdleTime,MaxPageSize,MaxPoolThreads,MaxQueryDuration,MaxValRange.

Once we get aware of the limits of the administration we should be able to Default the user setting.

After this go and view current policy setting...at the command prompt type LDAP setting press enter,then type in the connection and then once all the connection got displayed there and then see which all connection is not visible.This will make you known who all user are deleted at the LDAP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DirectorySearcher to list the Deleted objects with the Tombstone property set to true

```
using(DirectorySearcher srch = new DirectorySearcher(de))
    {
        //to return only deleted objects otherwise you can give any valid LDAP filter
        srch.Filter = "isDeleted=TRUE";

        // Instruct the DirectorySearcher to return deleted objects
        srch.Tombstone = true;

        srch.FindAll();
        //...


}
```